# Ionic 4: On building app getting "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" on Xcode 10.1 for ionic application

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cordova, ionic4

I have been trying to resolve the error for a week. Tried all the methods as updating pod, adding settings as "$(inherited)" etc. Nothing worked out.

Added the following in pod file.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'ProjectName' do
pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

**Error:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponent", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponentType", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponentContainer", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

> **Ionic Info**

**Ionic:**

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.8.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

**Cordova:**

```
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 28 other plugins)
```

**System:**

```
   NodeJS : v10.15.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS Mojave
   Xcode  : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

**Plugins Used:**

```
com-badrit-base64 0.2.0 "Base64"
com.moust.cordova.videoplayer 1.0.1 "Video Player"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 1.4.7 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.1 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support 1.6.0 "Cordova CocoaPods Dependency Support"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 2.5.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.5.1 "cordova-plugin-filepath"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.2.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-market 1.2.0 "Market"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.2 "Media"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 3.0.2 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.1.3 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-streaming-media 2.2.0 "StreamingMedia"
cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker 2.2.3 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-video-editor 1.1.3 "VideoEditor"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.4 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.2 "Toast"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.6.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
info.protonet.imageresizer 0.1.1 "Image Resizer"
ionic-plugin-deeplinks 1.0.17 "Ionic Deeplink Plugin"
```